# woocommerce call functions in order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin over woocommerce. I want when a order is completed some custom fields to be filled. After that I want to add those custom fields to the email sent to the client.
I have used

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'myplugin_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 1 );
```

to fill the custom fields and

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woo_add_tickets_numbers_to_email' );
```

to add those fields to email.

My problem seems tha woocommerce_email_order meta get fired before woocommerce_order_status_completed and the fields are empty.
How can I force to execute first woocomerce_order_status_completed and send email after that?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There is one way available to call `"woocomerce_order_status_completed"` this action before email send.

You can try using this code to trigger this function first,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
```

instead of,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'myplugin_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed,I dont understand exactly how to do that. Should I replace my line with your proposal?